# T-SQL: Помогите оптимизировать запрос

Tags: sql-server

Добрый день.

Есть запрос, который выполняется большое кол-во времени (даже примерно сказать не могу, больше 3ех минут). Таймаут на выполнение запроса стоит 1 мин, потом ее выполнение обрывается. Все индексы построены, в запрос 1 SELECT:

```
    SELECT
        p.[personId] as [personId],
        --r.[innerId],
        p.inn  as ИНН,
        ps.[firstNameRu] as [Имя рус.],
        ps.[lastNameRu] as [Фамилия рус.],
        ps.[middleNameRu] as [Отчество рус.],
        ps.[firstNameUa] as [Имя укр.] ,
        ps.[lastNameUa] as [Фамилия укр.],
        ps.[middleNameUa] as [Отчество укр.],
        ps.[birthday] as [Дата рождения],
        p.[phone] as Телефон,
        (
            select comment+',  ' from dbo.Reason  
            where personId = p.personId
            for xml path('')
        ) as Причина,
        CASE
            WHEN ps.[lostDate] IS NULL THEN 0
            WHEN ps.[lostDate] IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        END as [Паспорт потерян],
        ps.[series] as Серия,
        ps.[number] as Номер,
        ps.[office] as [Место выдачи],
        ps.[dateReceipt] as [Дата выдачи],
        p.[city] as Город,
        ps.[address] as Прописка
    FROM dbo.Person (NOLOCK) p
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Passport (NOLOCK) ps
      ON ps.personId = p.personId

    WHERE 

    --isnull(inn,0)=isnull(@inn,isnull(inn,0))

    (isnull(inn, 0)               = isnull(@inn,            isnull(inn,0))) AND
    (isnull([firstNameRu], 0)     = isnull(@firstNameRu,    isnull([firstNameRu],0))) AND
    (isnull([lastNameRu], 0)      = isnull(@lastNameRu,     isnull([lastNameRu],0))) AND
    (isnull([middleNameRu], 0)    = isnull(@middleNameRu,   isnull([middleNameRu],0))) AND
    (isnull([firstNameUa], 0)     = isnull(@firstNameUa,    isnull([firstNameUa],0))) AND
    (isnull([lastNameUa], 0)      = isnull(@lastNameUa,     isnull([lastNameUa],0))) AND
    (isnull([middleNameUa], 0)    = isnull(@middleNameUa,   isnull([middleNameUa],0))) AND
    ((@birthday is null) or (ps.[birthday] = @birthday)) AND
    (isnull([phone], 0)           = isnull(@contactPhone,   isnull(phone,0))) AND
    ----(@reason is null) or (
    ----    CONTAINS((
    ----        select comment+',  ' from dbo.Reason  
    ----        where personId = p.personId
    ----        for xml path('')
    ----    ), @reason)
    ----)) AND
    --(@PassportLost is null) or 
    --(
    --(CASE
    --  WHEN ps.[lostDate] IS NULL THEN 0
    --  WHEN ps.[lostDate] IS NOT NULL THEN 1
    --END) = @PassportLost
    --) AND
    (isnull([series], 0)        = isnull(@passportSeries, isnull([series],0))) AND
    (isnull([number], 0)        = isnull(@passportNumber, isnull([number],0))) AND
    (isnull([office], 0)        = isnull(@ktoVidal,       isnull([office],0))) AND
    ((@PassportReceivingDate is null) or ( [dateReceipt] = @PassportReceivingDate)) AND
    (isnull([city], 0)          = isnull(@City,           isnull([city],0))) AND
    (isnull([address], 0)       = isnull(@PassportAdress, isnull([address],0)))
```

Смысл запроса: у нас есть 2 связанные таблицы и большое число параметров. по которым может производиться отбор (всего около 15 параметров, причем могут быть заданы не все, а например только 1 фильтр, или 2 и 3ий)

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно оптимизировать запрос?**

Спасибо

План выполнения запроса показал, что 60% идет поиск в таблице Person:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нельзя просто так "оптимизировать запрос". Всегда нужно смотреть на план выполнения на конкретных данных. Желательно, обновив перед этим статистику для всех таблиц.

Comment: Посмотрите план на предмет большого количества строк / большого количества выполнений. Из самого запроса видно только что условия у вас дописываются неэффективно - они практически всегда перелопачивают все данные всех строк, даже если параметры для фильтрации не были переданы.

Comment: @PashaPash, добавил картинку с плана выполнения запроса - 60% времени идет поиск  в таблице Person

Comment: То, что "все индексы построены", не играет никакой роли. При условиях вида isnull(inn,0)=isnull(@inn,isnull(inn,0)) индексы использоваться не будут.

Comment: Зачем оставлять неиспользуемый код? Уберите лишние закомментированные участки кода. О каких объемах данных идет речь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я переписал запрос, и сделал его динамическим. Решило все проблемы. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Ок, по куску плана видна пара проблем:

Index scan на плане - это перебор всех строк в таблице Persons в поисках подходящих под фильтр. Фильтр у вас написан так, что он читает и проверяет все упоминаемые в нем колонки, даже если значение не было передано. Судя по толщине стрелок, данных в Persons достаточно много. Т.е. ваш запрос всегда перелопачивает всю базу.

Эффективного способа способа написать "если параметр спущен, то сравнить с ним", насколько я знаю, нет. Это одна из проблем выборки данных через хранимки. Вам придется строить SQL динамически, или на стороне приложения, или на стороне SQL Server, и выполнять его через sp_executesql (лучше первый вариант).

Вторая проблема - для каждой из выбранных строк SQL Server достает данные из Passport. Индекс, по которому он это делает - не покрывающий. т.е. для каждого из Person SQL Server

- лезет в индекс `IX_Passport_PersonId_IsЧтоТоТам`, как в наиболее подходящий (скорее всего в этом индексе первая колонка - `Passport.PersonID`), достает из этого индека `PassportID`.
- с этим `PassportID` лезет в `PK_Passport`, достает оттуда данные.

этого можно избежать, создав покрывающий индекс -

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Passport_For_Person] ON [dbo].[Passport]
(
    [personID] ASC
)
INCLUDE 
(
    [firstNameRu],
    -- и остальные колонки, которые показываются в плане в ноде Key Lookup
)
```

но это лучше сделать после динамического построения условий - может быть у вас key lookup вообще исчезнет.