# Поиск по нескольким параметрам

Tags: sql, sql-server

Пишу процедуру для выбора записей из таблицы.

Например таблица Resume с такими полями: "город", "категория", "дата создания", "название", "минимальная зарплата"...

в процедуру передаю все эти значения. Вот набросок

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindResumes
@city varchar(20),
@category varchar(20),
@date varchar(20),
@name varchar(20),
@minSalary double
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Resumes
    WHERE city = @city AND date = @date AND name = @name AND salary > @minSalary AND category = @category
END
```

Но это неправильный код, т.к.  не все аргументы будут заполнены. Например я буду проводить поиск только по **городу** и **категории**, а все остальные аргументы будут равны `null` и разумеется такой код и будет отбирать записи, в полях которых `null`, а мне же **нужно чтобы поиск проводился только по тем аргументам, которые я задам, а на незаполненные внимания не обращал**.

Да, можно сделать много процедур для всех комбинаций этих аргументов, но это не решение проблемы. Скажите пожалуйста как правильно решить мою задачу?

Comment: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) - рекомендую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE (@city is NULL OR city = @city) AND (@date is NULL OR date = @date) AND ...
```

Comment: Именно то, что мне нужно! Благодарю.

Comment: @Farad такой запрос [будеть читать все данные таблицы с диска, если не угадаете с индексами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/442836/177221). И даже если угадаете - будете читать целиком весь индекс, перебирая все строки. Стоит быть осторожнее с таким подходом на больших объемах данных.